# How to overcome null pointer initialisation error? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the initialisation at NULL of one pointer is bugging my program.

In order to not receive a compilation error, almost all the pointers in my code need to be initialise as nullptr like usual. Problem is, when I tried to use them afterwards, I get a whole bunch of errors telling me the null pointer is invalid. To overcome this error, the buggy pointers are now declare as an array. This way all my problems with this initialisation are gone. Everything seems to work fine until I realise one of my conditional branch was always returning false.

The full code is a bit too long and some parts use french words, so let's just paste what interest us...

```
struct Numero {
    int num;
    char client[50];
    Message *listeMessage = nullptr;
    Numero *suivant = nullptr;
    int nbmsg = 0;
};

char buff_char[50];
number = new Numero;
file >> number->client; // getting the right char client[50] from the file
if (number->client == buff_char)
                    break;
```

I also tried `if(*number->client == *buff_char)` without success. I'm now thinking that the problem is probably the array of char, but because of my previous problem I can't really change that so I'm hoping somebody can figure out what's going on here.

Note: Don't suggest anything related to strings, I can't use them because it's part of the challenge here to practice with pointers.

Comment: So, what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 2):

```
number->client == buff_char
```

Both of these are arrays, which decay into pointers. They are two different arrays with two different addresses, so this will always return false.

```
*number->client == *buff_char
```

This would compare the first element in each array, which is also not what you want.

You can use a standard library function like [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

If you can't use the standard library, loop over each array until one has a different element than the other (not equal), they both have `'\0'` (equal), or they both reach 50 (equal).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll do the loop thing if I don't find anything else. Like I ask another guy, do you have any idea why would I get an invalid null pointer when using a character pointer insted of a char array?

Comment: @JamesRoot What happens in this line `file >> number -> client`? Is the pointer automatically dereferenced to the first element?

Comment: I declare a pointer of char and initialising it at nullptr. Afterwards, I'm trying to get my value into it and it returns an error. The method is describe in my code (file >> buff_char). I did this because it was simple, but maybe a getline would be better and prevent all those bugs?

Comment: @Ramon maybe that's where all the errors are coming from but it's actually getting the value right and this method works everwhere else in my code without any errors.

Comment: @Ramon @Alexandre Blanchet I can't see what `file` is, but I'm assuming it expects the argument to be a pointer to a `char` buffer. The function has to dereference the pointer to write the data. Using the `getline` method in any `istream` is a good idea. It'll take the pointer and the maximum size it can write. If you don't allocate it enough memory (or any memory) you'll get a null pointer exception or a segfault (or worse).

Comment: @JamesRoot @Alexandre I just assumed it was an `std::ifstream`; I couldn't figure out which, if any, of the `operator >>` overloads would apply, hence the question. I agree about `getline` When you, Alexandre, say  it works, what exactly does it?

Comment: Ok i just tried the getline, it's getting the value right but It's still no helping with the condition. I think I'll need to imitate the strmcp sadly.

Comment: @AlexandreBlanchet Pointers are memory addresses. It's like a street address. I can build the same exact house on "1 Drive Road" and "2 Drive Road", but they are still two different addresses. Comparing them won't help me determine if they look the same. You gotta go into each house and check each room (dereference the pointer and check each element).

Comment: Even this is not working...`bool compare(char x[50], char y[50]) {
 for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  if (x[i] == y[i])
   continue;
  else
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}`

Comment: This: if (x[i] == y[i]) when it's get to the characters I didn't define it's returning false instantly, maybe I should put a condition to stop at \0?

Comment: `i < 50 && (x[i] || y[i])` This will exit the loop when both strings are found to be equal.

Comment: I understand this condition,but what if they're not equal?

Comment: @AlexandreBlanchet There are plenty of string comparison tutorials online you can use.

Comment: THANKS, it's working fine :) Can you just explain to me if you have time what the extra condition `&& (x[i] || y[i])` is actually testing?

Answer (score 1):

In `If` do a comparison instead of assignment

```
if (number->client == buff_char)
```

Comment: The actual code is already like that I did a mistake when copy pasting sorry about that :S

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `=` is the assignment operator. You want `==` for equality. What your if statement does right now is sets client equal to buff_char and then evaluates based on the newly assigned value of client.

Comment: The actual code is already like that I did a mistake when copy pasting sorry about that :S

Comment: No worries. What you're doing now is comparing the actual addresses of each pointer to each other which will always return false. If you want to compare two arrays of characters you can use strcmp. Read more here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: If you red my post correctly, I actually can't use any kind of string library.

Comment: No need to get sassy. I did read your post and strcmp is not in the string library. If you're hellbent on not using the STL, you could do it all yourself and create a function that iterates through each character array and compares their values at each index to see if the two arrays are equal.

Comment: I'm using a similar conditionnal branch elsewhere in my code but this time with int pointers and it's working fine. How can I put my char array buff_char back into a pointer so I can get it's value and compare it in the same way I did to others because like I said, when I tried that I get an error for using an invalid null pointer

Comment: I'll once again redirect you to strcmp. I know you can't use it but the documentation explains how it works. The function contains the functionality you're looking for so if you follow what it says the function does on cplusplus.com you'll have your algorithm.